# Python "while-loop" issue

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop

I wrote this Python-Script:

```
# random.py    This program displays a random number
#

import random

fl_running_0 = True

while fl_running_0:
    fl_running_1 = True

    print(str(random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))

    while fl_running_1 == True:
        str_input = input('Do you want to display another number? (yes/no) ')

        if str_input == 'yes' or str_input == 'y':
            fl_running_0 = True              # Optional -> just for readability
            fl_running_1 = False
        elif str_input == 'no' or str_input == 'n':
            fl_running_0 = False
            fl_running_1 = False
        else:
            print('Unexpected user input...try again!')
            fl_running_1 = True
```

I get an error ("Invalid Syntax") when I try to run it and I can't figure out why.
What did I wrong?

Greetings,
Lackmeier

Comment: At least write down the complete error to help us help you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line above:

```
print(str(random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])))
#                                     here--^
```

Comment: Oh, wow... Thank you. I just didn't noticed it because it just said Syntax Error on the latter line...

Comment: If the interpreter points out a syntax error on a line it's a good idea to check the previous line in most cases. Usually it's an unclosed (,{ or [ or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the friendly help. I'm quite new to Stackoverflow. Sorry if I didn't get everything concerning the forum instantly :D